# Java TreeMap.floorKey() equivalent for std::map

Tags: c++, search, library

I wanted something equivalent to this Java program:

> ```
> TreeMap<Integer,Integer> map = new TreeMap<Integer,Integer>();
>     map.put(10, 100);
>     map.put(20, 200);
>     map.put(30, 300);
>     map.put(40, 400);
>     map.put(50, 500);
>     map.put(60, 600);
>     map.put(70, 700);
>     map.put(80, 800);
>
>     System.out.println(map.floorKey(5));
>     System.out.println(map.floorKey(9));
>     System.out.println(map.floorKey(10));
>     System.out.println(map.floorKey(11));
>     System.out.println(map.floorKey(90));
> ```

output:

> ```
> null null 10 10 80
> ```

As there is no direct API to achieve the same in C++, I wrote the following code to implement a similar `floorKey()` function:

```
template <typename key,typename value>
int floorKey(map<key, value> input, int key)
{
    auto begin = input.begin();
    if (begin->first > key)//if key is less than the first key. It must retrun -1;
        return -1;

    auto end = input.end();
    end--;
    if (end->first < key)//if key is greater than last key, it must return last key
        return end->first;

    //if key is equal to any existing key, it should return the key
    auto find = input.find(key);

    if (find != input.end())
        return key;

    //Return the floor key for the given key
    auto lower = input.lower_bound(key);

    lower--;
    return lower->first;
}
```

Here's the test program:

```
int main()
{
    map<int, int> map;
    map.insert({ 10, 100 });
    map.insert({ 20, 200 });
    map.insert({ 30, 300 });
    map.insert({ 40, 400 });
    map.insert({ 50, 500 });
    map.insert({ 60, 600 });
    map.insert({ 70, 700 });
    map.insert({ 80, 800 });


    cout << floorKey(map, 5) << endl;
    cout << floorKey(map, 9) << endl;
    cout << floorKey(map, 10) << endl;
    cout << floorKey(map, 11) << endl;
    cout << floorKey(map, 90) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> ```
> -1 -1 10 10 80
> ```

Is there any better way to get the same?  Anything else I can improve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Headers and namespaces

The function is missing a definition of `map`.  This is probably what you want:

```
#include <map>

using std::map;
```

Similarly, the `main()` needs:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
```

That said, there's no good reason for `std::endl` in this code: an ordinary newline is sufficient, and we don't need the extra flushing behaviour of `std::endl`.

## Naming

It's an error to use the typename `key` as the name of a parameter here:

> ```
> template <typename key,typename value>
> int floorKey(map<key, value> input, int key)
> ```

It's pretty idiomatic to use PascalCase for template arguments, to distinguish them from function parameters:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
int floorKey(std::map<Key, Value> input, Key key)
```

(I've also corrected the function to accept the correct type for the `key` argument).

There's a similar problem in `main()`, where we have a conflict between the type `map` and our identifier `map`.  This is one of the reasons I'd argue against bringing the type name into the global namespace.

## Don't pass containers by value

We have a potentially large map, which we don't need to modify.  That suggests that it's better passed as a reference to a const object.  As we don't know the type of the key, we should probably assume that it's also better passed by reference (it could plausibly be a `std::string`, for example).  That gives us:

```
template<typename Key, typename Value>
int floorKey(const std::map<Key, Value>& input, const Key& key)
```

It's good that we used `auto` for the iterators `begin` and `end`, as it means that we don't need to change the body of the function to deal with them both now being const iterators.

## Don't over-constrain templates

This template will only match when the `key` argument has *exactly* the same type as the `input` argument's key.  That means that if we has a `std::map<long, char>`, we can't call passing an `int` key, even though `int` can be promoted to `long`.

And do we really need a `std::map()`?  Or would we like it to work with other map classes (e.g. `QMap` from Qt)?

A fix for this (using Concepts introduced in C++20 to help give better error messages when misused):

```
template<typename Map, typename Key>
auto floorKey(const Map& input, const Key& key)
    -> typename Map::key_type
    requires std::totally_ordered_with<Key,typename Map::key_type>
```

## Consider returning a map node

What's the use of having the lower-bound key?  In many cases, the caller will also want the corresponding value from the map.  It's easy to return these both at once using the map's `value_type`, saving a second lookup.

We can then provide convenience functions based on that to return just the key or just the value.

## Think about edge cases

What happens in this code when the `input` argument is an empty map?  We dereference `input.first()` without checking whether it's equal to `input.end()`, giving Undefined Behaviour at that point.

## Prefer prefix decrement

We have:

> ```
> auto end = input.end();
> end--;
> ```

It's slightly better to use `--end` there, as it eliminates any need to keep a copy for the value we're discarding.  Or we can avoid the need to mutate the variable, if we include `<iterator>`:

```
auto const end = std::prev(input.end());
```

## Algorithm

There's really no need to search for an exactly matching key if we then go on to call `lower_bound()` - we could just call `upper_bound()` instead, which will find the first key that's strictly greater than `key`, then decrement (if doing so is valid) to get the result:

```
auto it = input.upper_bound(key);

return it == input.begin()
    ? -1
    : (--it)->first;
```

Note that we have a problem here: if `Key` isn't a signed numeric type, then we can't return `-1`.  We really need a type-dependent value for this.  Better still, return a `std::optional`, so a defaulted value can be clearly distinguished from an actual result.

---

## Modified code

```
#include <concepts>
#include <map>
#include <optional>

template<typename Map, typename Key>
auto floorNode(const Map& input, const Key& key)
    -> std::optional<typename Map::value_type>
    requires std::totally_ordered_with<Key,typename Map::key_type>
{
    if (auto it = input.upper_bound(key);  it != input.begin()) {
        return *--it;
    }
    // not found
    return std::nullopt;
}

template<typename Map, typename Key>
auto floorKey(const Map& input, const Key& key)
    -> std::optional<typename Map::key_type>
{
    if (auto const node = floorNode(input, key); node) {
        return node->first;
    }
    // not found
    return std::nullopt;
}

template<typename Map, typename Key>
auto floorValue(const Map& input, const Key& key)
    -> std::optional<typename Map::mapped_type>
{
    if (auto const node = floorNode(input, key); node) {
        return node->second;
    }
    // not found
    return std::nullopt;
}
```

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<long, const char*> const map =
        {
         { 10, "G" },
         { 20, "F" },
         { 30, "E" },
         { 40, "D" },
         { 50, "C" },
         { 60, "B" },
         { 70, "A" },
         { 80, "A+" },
        };

    for (auto val: {5, 9, 10, 11, 90}) {
        std::cout << val << " -> "
                  << floorValue(map, val).value_or("U") << '\n';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Your code is obviously wrong:

```
template <typename key,typename value>
```

This line suggests that the code works for arbitrary maps, yet you require an `int key`, no matter what the key type of the map is.

Returning `-1` is not proper C++ style. You should return an iterator, as all other container functions do.

Passing the map by value makes an unnecessary copy of the whole map. Use a `const &` instead.

Answer (score 3):

You know about `lower_bound`/`upper_bound`; why not use just once and then see if the iterator is at the beginning and where the key in the returned iterator lands compared to the given key?

```
template <typename key,typename value>
int floorKey(map<key, value> input, int key)
{
    auto greater = input.upper_bound(key);

    if(greater == input.begin()) 
        return -1;

    assert(greater->first > key);

    --greater;
    return greater->first;
}
```

`upper_bound` always returns an iterator that is just past the key. So decrement it to get the floor.